# Typesetting question

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

I need your help please. How can I typeset this set (in the picture blew) in Latex. I even failed to write an attempt. I appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What does `{1}` following `\begin{array}` mean ?.

Comment: the `{l}` (that's an "ell", not a "one") means align the lines to the left.

Comment: Many thanks @barbarabeeton . This works fine.